# Receiving POST data from API on real time updates

Tags: php, api, post

I'm currently rather new to PHP and working on a project for my job that will take information about leads when they are updated from the sharpspring API and put it into Insightly's API. Sharpsrings API has a function, subscribeToLeadUpdates, that takes a url as a parameter and says it will POST the list of leads to the url whenever it is updated but I am confused about how exactly this works and how I would work with that information. Each time it POSTs will it run the script for the url that I gave it? I subscribed a url of a droplet I set up to test it with a dummy script that should just create a file whenever it is ran, and then tried testing it by updating a lead but nothing happened. Also if I update a lead and then run the script manually with a var_dump($_POST) it just dumps an empty array. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: that means the api will do an http request to YOUR server, for the specified url, and send over the data. that means YOU have to provide a script that can accept that post request and process the data being sent over. As far as the actual communications level stuff is concerned, it'll be a plain old HTTP request, like any other, that jus happens to be started by some code on the API's server, rather than someone clicking "submit" on a form in their browser.

Comment: When asking a question, please provide at least some code samples, with a degree of formatting to your post. 

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 

Try creating a post handling page (publicly accessible), and logging a var_dump of the request header, '$_POST', and 'file_get_contents('php://input')'

Comment: How would I go about setting that up? Everything I have read so far only says "just use php://input or $_POST" so I wrote a short script that just vardumps those and ran that manually after updating a lead but it dumps nothing. I set up the script at "serverip/APItest.php" and used that in the subscribe function I mentioned above. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Just checked the access logs for apache and it doesnt look like sharpspring is sending any POSTs. I ran their subscribe method and it returned "{"result":{"success":true},"error":null,"id":""}" and made sure there were no typos.. Is this just an error with their API?

Comment: @Missingo have you got your answer. i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

> I ran their subscribe method and it returned 
>   "{"result":{"success":true},"error":null,"id":""}"

That is correct, and means your request was accepted as valid.

There has to be some kind of activity with a lead that would trigger them trying to POST data to URL you sent...